Extracting metadata for a list of BOLD BINs
When I view the Public Data Portal page for a specific BOLD BIN, I get some useful metadata, including BIN Details (the image below is from this BIN):

I would like to be able to compile and download this data for a list of BINs, like for example, all the BINs associated with the Family Braconidae. I could not find a way to do this through the BOLD website. Is there a tool or an API plugin that would allow me to do this? This is not strictly a bioinformatics question, so if there is a stackexchange that is better suited I can move it there.
Edit:
To be specific, I would like to know the minimum, maximum, and mean distance within a given set of BINs, and the distance between those BINs their nearest neighbours, as is displayed in the image above.
Thanks,
Y.

What do you need exactly? Yes, the site has APIs, see https://boldsystems.org/index.php/api_home but you need to show us exactly what fields you want in order for us to be able to answer.

Thanks @terdon , I have edited the question to include specific details.
